# Geolocation of a Smartphone with GPS sensor

Tags: android, gps, geolocation

I'm trying to get GeoLocation of a user using the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(function() {

        var Geo={};

        if (navigator.geolocation) 
        {
           navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
        }

        //Get the latitude and the longitude;
        function success(position) {
            Geo.lat = position.coords.latitude;
            Geo.lng = position.coords.longitude;
            populateHeader(Geo.lat, Geo.lng);
        }

        function error(){
            console.log("Geocoder failed");
        }

        function populateHeader(lat, lng){
            $('#Lat').html(lat);
            $('#Long').html(lng);
        }

    });

  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="geo-coords">
     GeoLocation: 
     <span id="Lat">lat: ...</span>°,
     <span id="Long">long: ...</span>°
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried it on traditional desktop pc and seems work correctly (apart some approximation due to lack og GPS sensor) and also in my mobile Firefox on S4 Mini, but in this last case I have doubt that position is always determined by Wi-Fi or mobile linking and not by GPS sensor. Infact even if I turn GPS on and off, position with my smartphone is pretty always the same and quite different from real exact position detected by the same GPS on Google Maps.

How can I be sure that GPS sensor is the default sensor used?

Alternatively, do you have some other suggestion in order to track position of user device?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can only get the information what the API is offering, and quickly looking into the API docs at: [dev.w3.org](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html) I suppose the best you can do, is to check the **coords.accuracy**

Also do remember to set the enableHighAccuracy enabled, so then you could indeed get more accurate values.

Comment: I tried to create another example using Demo retrieved at this address: 
[CodeHandling Demo](http://www.codehandling.com/2012/12/jquery-plugin-to-get-location-of-your.html)

Here my version:
[My Version](http://www.mediagate.it/geolocation/)

I tried it with my Androidphone+firefox portable with and without GPS enabled and position seems always only one given by Mobile Cell and not by GPS sensor.......

Comment: Not seeing the codes for location fetching, anyway, your are using "..sensor=false" in there, which would indicate that no Sensor (GPS etc.) is used in there

Comment: You were right. I fix "sensor=true" but problem still persist. It seems that GPS location is completely ignored by my android phone....